# cant get a value from a json string

Tags: c#, json

The json string in the variable `content` I received is this :

```
"{\n \"predictions\" : [\n {\n \"description\" : \"9130 Beveren, Belgium\",\n \"id\" : \"96df4cd9b49e7ba4172485e91a4d268223886695\",\n \"matched_substrings\" : [\n {\n \"length\" : 4,\n \"offset\" : 0\n },\n 
{\n \"length\" : 7,\n \"offset\" : 14\n }\n ],\n \"place_id\" : \"ChIJk9NyZm8IxEcRDuOa4IbwK9Q\",\n \"reference\" : \"ChIJk9NyZm8IxEcRDuOa4IbwK9Q\",\n \"structured_formatting\" : {\n \"main_text\" : \"9130\",
\n \"main_text_matched_substrings\" : [\n {\n \"length\" : 4,\n \"offset\" : 0\n }\n ],\n \"secondary_text\" : \"Beveren, Belgium\",\n \"secondary_text_matched_substrings\" : [\n {\n 
\"length\" : 7,\n \"offset\" : 9\n }\n ]\n },\n \"terms\" : [\n {\n               \"offset\" : 0,\n \"value\" : \"9130\"\n },\n {\n \"offset\" : 5,\n \"value\" : \"Beveren\"\n },\n {\n \"offset\" : 14,\n \"value\" : \"Belgium\"\n }\n         ],\n \"types\" : [ \"postal_code\", \"geocode\" ]\n }\n ],\n \"status\" : \"OK\"\n}\n"
```

Same JSON with formatting for better readability:

```
{
    predictions : [
        {
            "description" : "9130 Beveren, Belgium",
            "id" : "96df4cd9b49e7ba4172485e91a4d268223886695",
            "matched_substrings" : [
                {
                    "length" : 4,
                    "offset" : 0
                },
                {
                "length" : 7,
                "offset" : 14
                }
            ],
            "place_id" : "ChIJk9NyZm8IxEcRDuOa4IbwK9Q",
            "reference" : "ChIJk9NyZm8IxEcRDuOa4IbwK9Q",
            "structured_formatting" : {
                "main_text" : "9130",
                "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
                    {
                        "length" : 4,
                        "offset" : 0
                    }
                ],
                "secondary_text" : "Beveren, Belgium",
                "secondary_text_matched_substrings" : [
                    {
                        "length" : 7,
                        "offset" : 9
                    }
                ]
            },
            "terms" : [
                {
                    "offset" : 0,
                    "value" : "9130"
                },
                {
                    "offset" : 5,
                    "value" : "Beveren"
                },
                {
                    "offset" : 14,
                    "value" : "Belgium"
                }
            ],
            "types" : [ "postal_code", "geocode" ]
        }
    ],
    "status" : "OK"
}
```

I need to retrieve the value for the `place_id` but I cant figure out how to do it.
What I expect as result is `ChIJk9NyZm8IxEcRDuOa4IbwK9Q`

I tried this

```
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(content);
string result = data["place_id"].ToString();
```

and this

```
string result = data["predictions.place_id"].ToString();
```

but they both return nothing.

If I do data ["predictions"] it returns something that has 8 rows, and I can see the variable ´place_id` with its value, but I dont known how to extract it.

What is the proper and fastest way of retrieving this value ?

Comment: All the backslashes in the string - are they actually in the string, or is that just what you're seeing in the debugger? If you could post the actual text, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: your `predictions` is an array so how many of your predictions are in this array and which predictions `place_id` you want to retrieve?

Comment: means if there are 5 predictions then which prediction's `place_id` you want to retrieve 1st or 2nd or 3rd or all?

Comment: thanks Georg I was just doing that myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a json formatter to format your json:

```
{  
   "predictions":[  
      {  
         "description":"9130 Beveren, Belgium",
         "id":"96df4cd9b49e7ba4172485e91a4d268223886695",
         "matched_substrings":[  
            {  
               "length":4,
               "offset":0
            },
            {  
               "length":7,
               "offset":14
            }
         ],
         "place_id":"ChIJk9NyZm8IxEcRDuOa4IbwK9Q",
         "reference":"ChIJk9NyZm8IxEcRDuOa4IbwK9Q",
         "structured_formatting":{  
            "main_text":"9130",
            "main_text_matched_substrings":[  
               {  
                  "length":4,
                  "offset":0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text":"Beveren, Belgium",
            "secondary_text_matched_substrings":[  
               {  
                  "length":7,
                  "offset":9
               }
            ]
         },
         "terms":[  
            {  
               "offset":0,
               "value":"9130"
            },
            {  
               "offset":5,
               "value":"Beveren"
            },
            {  
               "offset":14,
               "value":"Belgium"
            }
         ],
         "types":[  
            "postal_code",
            "geocode"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status":"OK"
}
```

`predictions` is actually an array. You need to specify which element of `prediction` before saying that you want the `place_id`. In this case there is only one element, so you can do `[0]`:

```
var result = data["predictions"][0]["place_id"];
```

But you might get multiple predictions in other cases. You need to decide which prediction you want the place id of.

Comment: Thanks, acually I expect only one, because this is a google api to get the place_id from a specific postal code in one country.

Answer (score 1):

Using your json

```
{
    predictions : [
        {
            "description" : "9130 Beveren, Belgium",
            "id" : "96df4cd9b49e7ba4172485e91a4d268223886695",
            "matched_substrings" : [
                {
                    "length" : 4,
                    "offset" : 0
                },
                {
                "length" : 7,
                "offset" : 14
                }
            ],
            "place_id" : "ChIJk9NyZm8IxEcRDuOa4IbwK9Q",
            "reference" : "ChIJk9NyZm8IxEcRDuOa4IbwK9Q",
            "structured_formatting" : {
                "main_text" : "9130",
                "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
                    {
                        "length" : 4,
                        "offset" : 0
                    }
                ],
                "secondary_text" : "Beveren, Belgium",
                "secondary_text_matched_substrings" : [
                    {
                        "length" : 7,
                        "offset" : 9
                    }
                ]
            },
            "terms" : [
                {
                    "offset" : 0,
                    "value" : "9130"
                },
                {
                    "offset" : 5,
                    "value" : "Beveren"
                },
                {
                    "offset" : 14,
                    "value" : "Belgium"
                }
            ],
            "types" : [ "postal_code", "geocode" ]
        }
    ],
    "status" : "OK"
}
```

You can use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject static method to deserliaze your json to a dynamic object then access its properties members, however using this method is risky because if the json gets changed the code will break.

```
 dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
 var palceId = obj.predictions[0].place_id;  //ChIJk9NyZm8IxEcRDuOa4IbwK9Q
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to convert it to class format for better approach and more readability and maintainability. below is a sample class of your JSON data.

```
public class MatchedSubstring
{
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
}

public class MainTextMatchedSubstring
{
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
}

public class SecondaryTextMatchedSubstring
{
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
}

public class StructuredFormatting
{
    public string main_text { get; set; }
    public IList<MainTextMatchedSubstring> main_text_matched_substrings { get; set; }
    public string secondary_text { get; set; }
    public IList<SecondaryTextMatchedSubstring> secondary_text_matched_substrings { get; set; }
}

public class Term
{
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Prediction
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public IList<MatchedSubstring> matched_substrings { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public StructuredFormatting structured_formatting { get; set; }
    public IList<Term> terms { get; set; }
    public IList<string> types { get; set; }
}

public class Prediction
{
    public IList<Prediction> predictions { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}


Prediction predictionJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Prediction>(jsonString);

string PlaceID=predictionJSON.predictions[0].place_id;
```